# In EntityFramework Core how do I get Owned Entity Type Order with specific order

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

CommentId.cs

```
public sealed class CommentId : AggregateRootId<Guid>
{
    public override Guid Value { get; protected set; }

    private CommentId(Guid value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    // omitted
}
```

ReplyId.cs

```
public sealed class ReplyId : ValueObject
{
    public Guid Value { get; }
}
```

Comment.cs

```
public class Comment : AggregateRoot<CommentId, Guid>, IHasDomainEvents
{
    private readonly List<Reply> _replies = new();
    public string Content { get; private set; }
    public MemberId SenderId { get; private set; }
    public DiscussionId DiscussionId { get; private set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<Reply> Replies => _replies.AsReadOnly();
    public DateTimeOffset CreateTime { get; private set; }
    
    // omitted...
}
```

Reply.cs

```
public class Reply : Entity<ReplyId>
{
    public string Content { get; set; } = null!;
    public MemberId ReceiverId { get; set; } = null!;
    public MemberId SenderId { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    // omitted...
}
```

CommentConfiguration.cs

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Comment> builder){

    // omitted...

    builder.OwnsMany(
       e => e.Replies,
       replyBuilder =>
            {
                replyBuilder.ToTable("Replies");
                replyBuilder.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("CommentId");
            }
       );
}
```

because the GUID type primary key,  i want  to get replies order by CreatedTime,but I don't see how I can configure it in that way

I expect to get Comment with Replies that is ordered by the createTime not the Id which is GUID type